# "read to" or "read for"

Tags: word-choice

The following sentence was given as an example of the use of “make time:”

> It's important to make time to read to your children.

I'm wondering if *read for* shouldn't be used here instead  of *read to*.
What are the differences?

Comment: Given as an example—but of what?

Comment: As an example for how the word *make time* is used.

Comment: The idiom is definitely _read [a story] to [a child]_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“To read to” means to read out loud—to someone.

> https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/read+to

You can read to your children, to a shut-in, and so forth.

The phrase *to read for* could mean reading for an audience or reading for a purpose, for example:

> I am reading my poetry for the garden club.

> I am reading for insight into the fall of Rome.

Comment: But you can also _read to_ an audience.

Comment: Yes, you could.